# How to make these functions stop interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have two functions, one plays a video on click (and changes the video that plays) on click, and then a function that is supposed to make a DIV's opacity go to zero. I tried to put them together because you're supposed to click on the same spot to activate both, but it doesn't work.

For some reason, when I put the div that contains the video (even without its function), the second function stops working. What can I do to make then work?

The function for the video player is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {
        var numb = $(this).index(),
            videos = ['images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v'],
            myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');

        myVideo.src = videos[numb]; 
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();

    });
});
```

And for the image:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('li', '.thumbs').click(function() {
            $('#MyT').addClass('clear');
        });
    });
});
```

I know that both shouldn't have `$(window).load(function()`, that just because these are the separate ones.

Comment: Are the 'clickable' elements dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but there is a typo in your code. `var numb = $(this).index(),` should be followed with a semicolon not a comma.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa um, they're added in a separate div, and are a list that. No.

Comment: @jmort253 - not when it's followed by another variabel, in this case an array.

Comment: @adeneo - Gotcha. Local scope vs global scope. My mistake! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your multiple selector syntax is what you want?, the comma separated selectors must be quoted just once if you want to apply it to all those element otherwise the you're just passing a `context`. In any case, I usually find the context unnecesary unless it's a previously cached selector. More info at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('li, .thumbs') // All `li` and all `.thumbs`
$('.thumbs li') // All 'li` within `.thumbs`
```

Notice that you're also using `(window).load()` and `(document).ready()`. When you combine both choose one or the other. There's a slight but important [difference](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/). Then you can combine everything like this and it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li, .thumbs').on('click', function () {

        // Add class
        $('#MyT').addClass('clear');

        // Video stuff
        var numb = $(this).index(),
            videos = [
                'images/talking1.m4v',
                'images/talking2.m4v', 
                'images/talking1.m4v', 
                'images/talking2.m4v', 
                'images/talking1.m4v', 
                'images/talking2.m4v'
            ],
            myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
            myVideo.src = videos[numb];

        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();

    });

});
```

Comment: I'd +1 this but I'm out of votes for the day. This is a much, much cleaner solution.

Comment: The selector is not wrong, it finds `li` elements inside the element with class `.thumbs`, and it's a valid selector. You've just changed it to include all `li` elements and all elements with the class `thumbs`, which could also work, who knows.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right! I fogot about the `context`. Don't know if that's what he's trying to do tho. OP?

Comment: Me neither, but I'll assume Nata2ha is a girls name, until proven otherwise :-) ...

Comment: @adeneo hahah, you're right, I'ma girl. I'm trying to make it so I click on a thumb, and the coresponding video in the array plays. And this works. So that's good :)

Comment: What can I add if the image div is supposed to reset and fade with each click?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine the two together like this?  I suspect that one of your click event handlers may be overriding the other click handler and causing it not to register.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {
        var numb = $(this).index(),
            videos = ['images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v'],
            myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
        myVideo.src = videos[numb]; 

        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();

        $('#MyT').addClass('clear');
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. For some reason a `<video>` tag disables the second one. Not even the function, I realized

Comment: Try elclanrs answer. I rarely see `$(window).load` used, which suggests that maybe you're taking the wrong approach at pageload time...

Answer (score 0):

If his doesn't work, separate the functions and call them with `window.onload(*function*)`.

Like this:

```
function vP() {
   $('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {
      var numb = $(this).index(),
      videos = ['images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v'],
      myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
      myVideo.src = videos[numb]; 
      myVideo.load();
      myVideo.play();
   });
}
function iM() {
   $('li', '.thumbs').click(function() {
      $('#MyT').addClass('clear');
   });
}
window.onload(iM();vP();)
```